# Python selenium displayed error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

First time I've ran into this error,

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(project_dir, 'chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
txt = open("aaa.txt")
driver.get("https://**.com/")
error_msg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="message"]/h3""")
for line in txt.readlines():
    if error_msg.is_displayed():
        print("test")
    print(line)
    driver.get("https://steamcommunity.com/id/" + line)
```

Basically what happens is I get thrown an error when I try too start it.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

Comment: Please kindly add your error message.

Comment: Unluckily you posted the least relevant part of the traceback. You should add it completely.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp